# 2 Pods picking up same database row with event triggers

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, openshift, scheduled-tasks

Same Spring boot application is running on 2 pods. Application has scheduler running with a cron job and picking up data from database ( JDBC Connection - JPA) . Both the pods are fetching same row from database which is causing duplicate requests.
How to avoid such situation.

There should not be duplicate requests sent and if data is picked by 1 pod then other pods should not process same data.

Comment: Do you want the job to run potentially concurrently on all pods or run on any single pod? If you want the job to run on any single pod, then you could use Quartz jobs/scheduling configured in cluster mode. In cluster mode Quartz will make sure the job is dispatched to a single pod. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/io.html#io.quartz) for more info on the Spring Boot Quartz starter.